# Creating board game on android

Tags: java, android, arrays, canvas

I'm a bit new on Android development and I've been given a task to development a board game. I have managed to draw the board using the canvas class and now what's left is to introduce the objects at each point so they can move along the lines as part of game play. I already have the rules of the game but now my question is:

How do I trace which point I clicked from the board so that it can be recognized by the rules class. e.g If I click at point number one it should know from the array that board[0] is clicked?

Please help.
This is how I have drawn the board on canvas.

```
 public class BoardGame extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread thread = null;
    boolean canDraw = false;
    Canvas canvas;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Paint black, blackDot, background,paint;
    Path tri;
    Path d_square = new Path();
    public BoardGame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    }
    //For making the board suit every screen
    private int toPxs(int dps) {
        return (int) (dps * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
    //Drawing the board everytime the game starts
    public void run() {
        prepPaintBrushes();
        while (canDraw == true) {
            if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);
            drawDensitySquare(50, 200, 270, 390);
            drawDensitySquare(160, 90, 160, 500);
            triangle(160,90,270,200,50,200);
            triangle(160,500,50,390,270,390);
            triangle(50, 200,270,390,50,390);
            triangle(270,200,270,390,50,390);
            drawDensitySquare(50,200,270,295);
            pieces(160,90,6,paint);
            canvas.drawPoint(50,200,paint);
            canvas.drawText("Game Score: ", getX() + 20, getY()+50, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Turn: ", getX()+300, getY()+50, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Moves: ", getX()+20, getY()+90, paint);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    //Paint brushes used
    private void prepPaintBrushes() {
        black = new Paint();
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        black.setStrokeWidth(2);

        blackDot = new Paint();
        blackDot.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        blackDot.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        background = new Paint();
        background.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        background.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
    }

    public void pieces(int x,int y,int r, Paint paint){
        int xdp1,ydp1,rd;
        xdp1 =toPxs(x);
        ydp1 = toPxs(y);
        rd = toPxs(r);
        this.canvas.drawCircle(xdp1,ydp1,rd,paint);

    }
    private void drawDensitySquare(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        int xdp1, ydp1, xdp2, ydp2;
        xdp1 = toPxs(x1);
        ydp1 = toPxs(y1);
        xdp2 = toPxs(x2);
        ydp2 = toPxs(y2);

        d_square.moveTo(xdp1, ydp1);
        d_square.lineTo(xdp2, ydp1);

        d_square.moveTo(xdp2, ydp1);
        d_square.lineTo(xdp2, ydp2);

        d_square.moveTo(xdp2, ydp2);
        d_square.lineTo(xdp1, ydp2);

        d_square.moveTo(xdp1, ydp2);
        d_square.lineTo(xdp1, ydp1);

        this.canvas.drawPath(d_square, black);
    }

    private void triangle(int x1,int x2,int x3,int x4,int x5,int x6) {
        tri = new Path();

        int xdp1, xdp3, xdp2, xdp4, xdp5, xdp6;
        xdp1 = toPxs(x1);
        xdp2 = toPxs(x2);
        xdp3 = toPxs(x3);
        xdp4 = toPxs(x4);
        xdp5 = toPxs(x5);
        xdp6 = toPxs(x6);

        tri.moveTo(xdp1, xdp2);
        tri.lineTo(xdp3, xdp4);

        tri.moveTo(xdp3, xdp4);
        tri.lineTo(xdp5, xdp6);

        tri.moveTo(xdp5, xdp6);
        tri.lineTo(xdp1, xdp2);
        this.canvas.drawPath(tri, black);
    }
    public void pause() {
        canDraw = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        thread = null;
    }
    public void resume() {
        canDraw = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

---

And these are the rules and the structure of the board.

```
            01

      02    03    04

      05    06    07

      08    09    10

            11
```

public class Rules {

```
private int[] board;
private final int EMPTY_FIELD = 0;
private int blackMarkers;
private int whiteMarkers;
private int turn;
public Rules() {
    board = new int[12];
    blackMarkers = 3;
    whiteMarkers = 1;
}
public boolean validMove(int from, int to) {
    //Not a valid move
    if(!isValidMove(from, to)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Move the marker to it's new position
    board[to] = board[from];
    board[from] = EMPTY_FIELD;

    // Change turn
    if(turn == Constants.WHITE) {
        turn = Constants.BLACK;
    } else {
        turn = Constants.WHITE;
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean isValidMove(int from, int to) {
    //Can only move to it's neighbors.
    switch (to) {
        case 1:

            return (from == 2 || from == 3 || from == 4);
        case 2:
            return (from == 1 || from == 3 || from == 5 || from == 6);
        case 3:
            return (from == 1 || from == 2 || from == 4|| from == 6);
        case 4:
            return (from == 1 || from == 3 || from == 6|| from == 7);
        case 5:
            return (from == 2 || from == 6 || from == 8);
        case 6:
            return (from == 2 || from == 3|| from == 4|| from == 5|| from == 7|| from == 8|| from == 9|| from == 10);
        case 7:
            return (from == 4 || from == 6|| from == 10);
        case 8:
            return (from == 5 || from == 6 || from == 9|| from == 11);
        case 9:
            return (from == 6 || from == 8|| from == 10|| from == 11);
        case 10:
            return (from == 6 || from == 7 || from == 9|| from == 11);
        case 11:
            return (from == 8 || from == 9 || from == 10);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean canRemove(int partOfLine) {
    // Check if the argument is part of a line on the board
    if(board[partOfLine] == EMPTY_FIELD) {
        return false;
    }

    if((partOfLine == 1 || partOfLine == 2) && (board[1] == board[2])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 1 || partOfLine == 4) && (board[1] == board[4])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 8 || partOfLine == 11) && (board[8] == board[11])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 10 || partOfLine == 11) && (board[10] == board[11])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 2 || partOfLine == 3 || partOfLine == 4) && (board[2] == board[3] && board[3] == board[4])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 2 || partOfLine == 6 || partOfLine == 10) && (board[2] == board[6] && board[6] == board[10])) {
        return true;
    }

    if((partOfLine == 2 || partOfLine == 5 || partOfLine == 8) && (board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 4 || partOfLine == 7 || partOfLine == 10) && (board[4] == board[7] && board[7] == board[10])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 4 || partOfLine == 6 || partOfLine == 8) && (board[4] == board[6] && board[6] == board[8])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 1 || partOfLine == 3 || partOfLine == 6 || partOfLine == 9 || partOfLine == 11) && (board[1] == board[3] && board[3] == board[6] && board[6] == board[9] && board[9] == board[11])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 5 || partOfLine == 6 || partOfLine == 7) && (board[5] == board[6] && board[6] == board[7])) {
        return true;
    }
    if((partOfLine == 8 || partOfLine == 9 || partOfLine == 10) && (board[8] == board[9] && board[9] == board[10])) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}